# Error when trying to install Minecraft - no such file in directory

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to install Minecraft on my Pi. I have the file downloaded. However, when I try to start Minecraft it says that the file doesn’t exist, when it is clearly there. You can see from the picture I took.[image: screen]

Any help it greatly appreciated.

Comment: I cannot see anything on the picture. Can you please paste the text on the pictures direct into the question?

Comment: What file are you talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not specified what you have done, or even what OS and Pi you are using.

There should be no need to install anything!

Minecraft is included in Raspbian - if not it can be added using the `Recommended Software` Menu.